# Question about JPQL, @NamedQuery

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, jpql

If I have something like this

```
@Entity
public class Facility {
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="CUSTOMER_FK")
    private Customer customer;
    ...
}
```

does my `@NameQuery` like this

```
@NamedQuery(name="Facility.findByCustomerId", query="select c from Facility c where c.customer=:customer_fk")
```

or like this

```
@NamedQuery(name="Facility.findByCustomerId", query="select c from Facility c where c.CUSTOMER_FK=:customer_fk")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to stop thinking foreign keys and to start thinking object when using JPQL. Let's take a closer look:

```
select c from Facility c where c.CUSTOMER_FK=:customer_fk
```

Does your `Facility` have a `CUSTOMER_FK` property? No, so the above query is incorrect. Next one:

```
select c from Facility c where c.customer=:customer_fk
```

Syntacticly, this one is correct. But you're still not thinking object. Here, the query expect you to pass **an instance of customer**, not a FK. I'd thus rewrite it like this (it *is* the same query but it communicates IMO the intention much better and I'd actually avoid any `foo_fk` convention, you don't really manipulate FK with JPA):

```
select c from Facility c where c.customer = :customer
```

And if you really want to find by id, you should navigate through the association and write:

```
select c from Facility c where c.customer.id = :id
```

Comment: much better understand after seeing your post. TYVM

Comment: I hope it ok if I ask another question. if I do this `select c from Facility c where c.customer.id = '1'"`. Then I got what I want. But if I do this `select c from Facility c where c.customer.id = :id`, then in my Enterprise Bean. I do `Query query.setParameter("id", "1")` then I get nothing. Any idea why?

Comment: @Harry What is the type of `id`?

Comment: type `Long`. I try to convert `Long.parseLong("1")`, but still no go

Comment: Yeah it work. And I try this and it work as well, `query.setParameter("id", new Long("1"))`. Thanks a lot man :)

Answer (score 1):

In JPQL you use the names of the properties, not the database columns. So - the first option.

But when you pass parameters, you pass the whole objects, not their IDs. In your case, you either pass a `Customer` instance, or make the where clause look for `c.customer.id` (and you'd better name the alias `f`, not `c`)

Comment: when I try to do this `@NamedQuery(name="Facility.findByCustomerId", query="select c from Facility c where c.customer = '1'")`. I got nothing return back. Did I do something wrong?